# How to set python paths in xlwings Excel without changing %PATH% environment variable?

Tags: xlwings

I have installed xlwings 0.15.5 and use UDF to call my python code (Windows 10, Excel 2016). I have found out that in order to find all the dependencies, I had to extend `%PATH%` with the following.

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\usr\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\mingw-w64\bin
```

I do not think that changing `%PATH%` is the best way and most likely I have missed something during the installation but I couldn't find out what I could have missed. Can you please bring some light here?

Comment: I think you're hitting this issue: https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/issues/954

Comment: Thx @FelixZumstein. I came through this thread while looking for the issue. This is where I got the tip about extending my %PATH% variable. However I'm looking for a better way of handling python environments dynamically, which seems to be still something in the pipe of xlwings according to the same post.

Comment: yes this should be fixed soon

Comment: Thx @FelixZumstein, keep us posted.

Comment: @FelixZumstein any updates on the availability of the fix? Thanks,

Comment: Yes, conda support has been released.